# Filling a jQuery autocomplete list with webservice data?

Tags: jquery, web-services, autocomplete

This is my Webservice responsible to fill the autocomplete:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[WebMethod]
public List<Farms> GetFarms1()
{
    PlaseTableAdapter pta = new PlaseTableAdapter();
    PlaseLande.PlaseDataTable pdt = pta.GetData();

    List<Farms> farms = new List<Farms>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in pdt)
    {
        string farmName = (string)dr["FARMNAME"];
        string farmID = (string)dr["FARMID"];
        farms.Add(new Farms(farmID, farmName));
    }
    return farms;
}


 public class Farms
    {
        public Farms(string farmid, string farmname)
        {
            FARMID = farmid;
            FARMNAME = farmname;
        }

        public string FARMID { get; set; }
        public string FARMNAME { get; set; }
    }

}
```

This is the jquery to get the json data from the webservice

```
$("#txtFarms").autocomplete("WebService.asmx/GetFarms1", {
                        dataType: 'json',
                            parse: function(data) {
                                var parsed = [];
                                data = data.Farms;

                                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                    parsed[parsed.length] = {
                                        data: data[i],
                                        value: data[i].FARMNAME,
                                        result: data[i].FARMNAME
                                    };
                                }

                                return parsed;
                            },
                            formatItem: function(item) {
                                alert(item);
                                return item.FARMNAME + ' (' + item.FARMID + ')';
                            }
                        });
```

My code isn't working, what am I missing?

Comment: It fills a jQuery autocomplete list using the webservice atleast that is what I want it to do.

Comment: @user No, like, what happens when you run the code? We need to know what's wrong with it before we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

look for return an real json. i think that you should add an dataAnnotation..

```
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

so in your code :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Farms> GetFarms1() // why you don't have no parameter like the term of search ?
{
PlaseTableAdapter pta = new PlaseTableAdapter();
PlaseLande.PlaseDataTable pdt = pta.GetData();

List<Farms> farms = new List<Farms>();
foreach (DataRow dr in pdt)
{
    string farmName = (string)dr["FARMNAME"];
    string farmID = (string)dr["FARMID"];
    farms.Add(new Farms(farmID, farmName));
}
return farms;
}
```

see [How to return JSON from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447538/how-to-return-json-from-webservice)

```
  $( "#txtFarms" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
         url: "WebService.asmx/GetFarms1",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {
         name_startsWith: request.term // i don't see it in your code ... why?
         },
         success: function( data ) {
         response( $.map( data.Farms, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.FARMNAME + ' (' + item.FARMID + ')';,
            value: item.FARMNAME
          }
        }));
      }
    });
```

more information : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

It helps you?