# How to return JSON from webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

Morning,

I need to return a message from my web service. Below is a sample of my code, and i am returning a string.

```
[web method]
public string CheckFeedSubmission()
    {
        string responseText = "";
        try
        {
            //Stuff goes here
            responseText = "It Worked!"
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { responseText = "Opps wehave an error! Exception message:" + ex.Message; }
        return responseText ;
    }
```

I currently get the following response...

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
```

I would ideally like to return something like

```
 {"success" : true, "message" : "***Message Here***"}
```

I am sure once i get the idea of it, i will be able to return other items if needed. Its just this base i need to work out.

All help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

UPDATE: Just found this...

```
 return "{Message:'hello world'}"
```

Would i need something like

```
 responseText = "{"success" : true, "message" : \"There has been an error. Message: " + ex.Message + "\"}"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [web service should return json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205081/web-service-should-return-json)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Use:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]//Specify return format.
public string CheckFeedSubmission()
    {
        string responseText = "";
        try
        {
            //Stuff goes here
            responseText = "It Worked!"
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { responseText = "Opps wehave an error! Exception message:" + ex.Message; }
        return responseText ;
    }
```

**The result returned will be like:**

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
 {"success" : true, "message" : "***Message Here***"}
</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as above i still get XML string back

Comment: Actually it returns Json inside the XML. You need to specify in your call what you want to return. Why it returns in the format? http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: Have a re-look at the answer.

Comment: and is there no way to remove the <string> element?

Comment: Yes you can, have a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121559/asp-net-json-web-service-always-return-the-json-response-wrapped-in-xml

Comment: arr i see, just tested in my app rather than my actual web service and its returning json. Just need to format it so I have what i want returning :)

Would i be assuming correctly if i add a bool like i did with the responseText to pass over a true/false ?

Comment: How to get complete JSON form with out any XML Tag !

Answer (score 2):

Please use the attribute for your webmethod

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

The caller will have set his contenttype to application/json to use the webmethod

Comment: does not work, still only get a string back - <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">It worked alright</string>

Answer (score 1):

To remove the XML tags in your service response, see this answer on StackOverflow:

[ASP.NET WebService is Wrapping my JSON response with XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058454/asp-net-webservice-is-wrapping-my-json-response-with-xml-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
[WebMethod] 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]//Specify return format. 
public bool addUser(UserModel um)
    {
        bool result = false;
        result = Conversion.intToBool(SplashAwardsDB.executeNonQuery(
            "INSERT INTO dbo.User ("
            + "userName, password, firstName, lastName, address, contactNo, birthDate, familyID, familyRole, x, y ) "
            + " VALUES ("
            + "'" + um.userName + "', "
            + "'" + um.password + "', "
            + "'" + um.firstName + "', "
            + "'" + um.lastName + "', "
            + "'" + um.address + "', "
            + "'" + um.contactNo + "', "
            + "'" + um.birthDate + "', "
            + "'" + um.familyID + "', "
            + "'" + um.familyRole + "', "
            + "'" + um.x + "', "
            + "'" + um.y + "')"
            ));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This my solution for the framewok 4.5.2,
In the class FilterConfig add the following code,
Note: you will need the lib Newtonsoft.

```
 public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors();
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```